# Kinetic JS constantly redraws after stopAnimation() is called

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm using Kinetic JS as it provides some useful event handlers for individual items on canvas.

After finishing drawing, I run:

```
kin.stopAnimation();
```

To stop animating. And:

```
console.dir(kin);
```

Shows 'animating: false'. However when I move the mouse anywhere over the canvas element, it seems

```
 kin.setDrawStage()
```

fires its callbacks again and the scene redraws.

My scene is complex - I have a lot of items and graphics - but not animated (click handlers just add a DOM object on top of the canvas). The constant redrawing makes the canvas unusably slow when using Kin.

How can I stop Kin from unnecessarily redrawing?

Comment: Note that not redrawing each object on the canvas (eg, checking for a variable in setDrawStage) will stop Kinetic's event handlers from firing.

Comment: After the testing above, I ended up porting my entire application to Cake.JS, which allows events on individual canvas items without unnecessary redraws. Performance is greatly improved.

Comment: ah that's a shame.  Perhaps you were using an old vesion of KineticJS?  This issue has been fixed in recent versions, including v1.0.4